# Isotope 2 with "BJ Lazy Load" Wordpress plugin: damned overlap

Tags: lazy-loading

Please help me.

I use this fantastic "Isotope" in this way:

```
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery('#container').imagesLoaded( function() {
    jQuery('#container').isotope({
      itemSelector: '.item',
      layoutMode: 'masonry',
      stamp: '.stamp1'
    });
  });
});
```

With "BJ Lazy Load" Wordpress plugin activate there is everywhere an overlap of div.

With the plugin deactivate I see everything fine.

How to fix this?

If in the settings section of the Wordpress plugin i put "Load in Head" rather than "Load in Footer" the problem is partially fixed. There is less overlap, but some are still there, especially after one or two scroll with the mouse.